# Как использовать опредённый класс из другого php файла

Tags: php

Есть файл `Utilis.php`.

В нем есть `Class User`.

Как класс использовать в другом файле этот класс?

Comment: Эм, `require_once`?

Comment: Cannot declare class Struct\User, because the name is already in use

Comment: Он уже у вас подгружен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через пространство имен. Например:

```
$user = new Classes\User($params);
$user->getUser($id);
```

А в Utilis.php указать:

```
namespace Classes;
```

P.S. Либо да, require_once.